# Tensorflow CNN output as a matrix of a different shape than the input matrix

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, chess

I have prepared myself a dataset of chess games which contains of features represented by 6x8x8 tensors (6 layers each one is a board representing a chess piece in both colors). The labels in the dataset are tensors in shape 2x8x8 (2 boards representing the next optimal move - first one shows where is the piece to move and the second one where the piece is moved). How can I structure the network to take batches of boards and output probabilities of a pawn to move and where to move it in my desired format?

Tried using Conv2D layers as well as Conv2DTranspose layers, the sizes dont seem to match no matter what I do

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(6, 8, 8)),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='selu'),
tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='selu'),
tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3), padding="same", activation="selu"),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(2, (3, 3), padding="same", activation="selu")
```

Here is a example code of my network.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf

conv_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', activation='relu', input_shape=(height, width, channels))
```

When the stride is 1 and no padding is used, the spatial dimensions of the output feature maps can be calculated using the following formulas:

```
Output Height = (Input Height - Filter Height + 1)
Output Width = (Input Width - Filter Width + 1)
```

If padding is added, the formulas become:

```
Output Height = ((Input Height - Filter Height + 2 * Padding) / Stride) + 1
Output Width = ((Input Width - Filter Width + 2 * Padding) / Stride) + 1
```